# How to upload file/bitmap to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to upload a list of file/bitmap to Cloud Firestore.

First I would like to upload a single file/bitmap but I have many errors.

```
 private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
  //...
  db.collection("CarShop").document("Cars").set(mFile);
```

Comment: Which errors to you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following the way you can upload a file to Firebase Cloud Storage

```
 FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
 // Create a storage reference from our app
 StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
 Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/rivers.jpg"));
StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
        // ...
    }
});
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#upload_from_a_local_file).

For Bimap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, etc.
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: if i hava custom class and list with Bitmap inside, how  i can do it ?

Comment: just loop it. It's a async.. so will work in any case. also, accept the answer if helpful.

Comment: but what about private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();?when to use it?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check! You will need `FirebaseStorage`, not `FirebaseFirestore`. while creating `riversRef` you can modify the path as required.

Comment: but i use Firestore. Or is it the same?

Comment: You should read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files and https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-example/